# Context sensitive help in Visio

Tags: vba, visio

In Visio I am developing some shape stencils, and in Visio 2010 when you hover over a master there is a "More" hyperlink that opens Visio help.

Is it possible to hook into that hyperlink and show my own help for that master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add it to the Help field for the master (under Developer [tab] / Shape Name).  Have a look at this article for details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa201737%28office.10%29.aspx